# React Native app asks iOS location permissions on first launch, but 0 references to geo/location code anywhere inside

Tags: ios, react-native, ios11, react-native-ios

So I have a React Native app, and when testing in iOS, on first launch it always asks for location while in use (within 1 second of opening). ie. "Allow XXX to access your location while you are using the app?" permission dialog.

I am using react-native-permissions for other stuff, but I've searched and searched my code and have 0 references to "geolocation","location","navigator",etc. Basically there no location code or geolocation code anywhere to be found.

Looking for help on how to diagnose this crazy issue. In my NPM modules, again nothing crazy there either that would depend on location. I've even deleted the "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" from info.plist and app still launches, doesn't crash and never prompts location dialog!

(This is on iOS 11.3)

Looking for advice.

Thanks

Comment: Same happening to me.. did you sole the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Info.plist, you probably have either of these keys, or both:

```
NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
```

As a result iOS will prompt for location access as soon as you launch your app.

Comment: is there any way to location permission ask when require only?